# Can I automatically open specific namespaces and libraries in F# Interactive REPL?

Tags: f#, read-eval-print-loop, visual-studio-addins, fsi

I notice that each time I open [F# Interactive (FSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/) from within Visual Studio to tryout something [REPL-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), I always find myself executing a few commands first, often specific for any given project:

```
open System;;
#r @"r:\projects\currentprjLibs.dll";;
#r @"r:\external\unquote.dll";;
#time;;
```

This is just an example, but I find myself asking: can this be automated? Now, I could have an `fsx` script for each project and do a "send to interactive", but this is still quite a bit of work (and `#r` or `#time` won't work there). Besides, I have to do it again on each FSI Reset.

Does anybody know of a simpler way? Should I roll my own (I never created a serious add-in for Visual Studio, but maybe now is a good time). Other suggestions?

---

*<sub>PS: the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982841/f-interactive-reference-a-project-in-currently-open-solution?rq=1) is not what I am after, as it applies to every instance of FSI and it doesn't do `opens`. The 2nd solution there is to add `#if INTERACTIVE`, but this adds clutter, is difficult to write with relative paths, and `Ctrl-A` plus `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` will choke on any `namespace`, which then also needs to be in `#if !INTERACTIVE`, adding more clutter.</sub>*

Comment: I remember a long time ago that we had a similar need on a project and the ideal solution was to have a dependency tree, and then you use only one reference and the rest get brought in because of the dependencies. It was an F# suggestion but I don't know if it was ever implemented. The idea came about when translating OCaml to F#. See: [Dependency generator (ocamldep)](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/depend.html)

Comment: IIRC you seek [OCaml #use](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec275) but for F#.

Comment: Found the F# User Voice request. It was declined. [Fix the #use directive in F# interactive](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5670098-fix-the-use-directive-in-f-interactive) If that is acceptable as an answer, let me know.

Comment: What we finally did for the project was to just open everything and do it with one fsx file. [init_all.fsx](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/Examples/init_all.fsx)

Comment: @guy, your last comment is something we used to do as well, but it is suboptimal at best and still requires quite a few steps on each session, which defies the idea or usefulness of REPL, I think.

Comment: I should have noted that `init_all.fsx` is not a suggestion or answer, but what we finally did. We were not pleased either.